# Alternatives to if else nesting for command line parsing

Tags: if-statement, logic, command-line-arguments

I am creating a bot which will take in commands starting with `!command` then it will have actions like `poll` or `help`.
These actions will have further options and they can be variable in number.
For example: 
`!command poll create somepollurl`
If somepollurl is omitted, it should take a default url. 
(Above is just an example of how complicated the logic can be.)

Currently the code which I have is getting too much nested and hence less readable and difficult to maintain. This may also lead to bugs and unexpected loopholes in the logic that may be exploited by malicious users.

I was wondering if there could be better ways to deal with the issue so that the code is more readable and bug free.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a library instead of trying to do it manually. Since you don't say which language you are working in, I can't recommend a specific library, but any language anyone uses will have one (and probably more than one).

Comment: Hey, I am using nodejs. I can't think of a library that could do what I want. Can you show any example? Any language will do if not node js. Atleast I will get the idea

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args, https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander, https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist, http://yargs.js.org/. There are probably more. Look at their documentation to see if they can do what you want and pick one whose API you like best.